Is the first heaven close
Does Quran 22:65 mean that the first heaven is close enough to fall on the earth, ive read that it surrounds the universe

Blockquote
وَيُمْسِكُ ٱلسَّمَآءَ أَن تَقَعَ عَلَى ٱلْأَرْضِ
And He holds the sky lest it falls on the earth

